# Horizontal scrolling with iframe and jquerymobile

Tags: jquery-mobile

I have another question on stackoverflow, that is similar to this but different.

My problem is that the width of the content is wider than the widow. the scoll up and down works but the horizontal scroll does not

The code snippet is

```
 <div class="custommenu scrollablediv"  id="mycontent" data-role="content" style="padding:0;">
            <iframe scrolling="yes"  id="myiframe" src="/user/custom/curl.php?<?=$customMenuID?>"  width="100%" height="600" seamless ></iframe>
 </div>
```

i also tried adding some javascript to the iframe page that returns the height and width of the page and then setting the iframe width to that.

Still no horizontal scroll.

Thanks for any help

Comment: same issue.. did you find any solution?

Answer (score 0):

You can try by adding css on parent of your iframe.

```
-webkit-overflow-scrolling:touch
```

for more details check 
http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.0.1/docs/pages/touchoverflow.html